# DrawerLayout (with FrameLayout) crashes on orientation changes

Tags: android, layout

I have implemented the PagerSlidingTabStrip with success (it contains a viewpager).
Then, i put a DrawerLayout with a listview above with success (yehh).

Then, i replace the Listview by a FrameLayout with a fragment inside so to have a fragment in my drawer.

It's working but crashes on orientation change. I have no idea why.

Here's the working xml.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/theme_color" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blanccasse" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>    

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If i replace the listview by

```
     <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/gris" >    

</FrameLayout>
```

it crashes on orientation change.

Any ideas ?? Thanks.

**EDIT :**

The logcat is : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$SavedState

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The id (`android:id` tag) from the `DrawerLayout` is the same as the `id` on the `FrameLayout` you use to replace the `ListView`.

Comment: Ok. You're right. Something you just doesn't see the things just under your nose. Thanks.